# Read wkwebview Consol.log

Tags: ios, swift

I have web view application and try To Read All Of The javascript Console.log and clicked event of the web view in my application

I write this code , when button is clicked go to userContentController delegate but when have message nothing happen

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let source = """
        document.addEventListener('click', function(){ window.webkit.messageHandlers.iosListener.postMessage('click clack!'); })
        document.addEventListener('message', function(e){
            window.webkit.messageHandlers.iosListener.postMessage(e.data); })
        })
        """
        let script = WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)
        config.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
        config.userContentController.add(self, name: "iosListener")
```

How can I read console.log of wkwebview messages swift?
 in UIwebview I can use

```
 let context = self.webView.value(forKeyPath: "documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext") as! JSContext

        let logFunction : @convention(block) (String) -> Void =
        {
            (msg: String) in

            NSLog("Console: %@", msg)
        }
       context.objectForKeyedSubscript("console").setObject(unsafeBitCast(logFunction, to: AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "log" as NSString)
```

but in wkwebview it dosent work

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well you want to redirect the console.log of the document to your app log.

I would suggest this solution:

This is the script to add to your webview using `WKUserScript` as you did.

```js
    var console = (function (oldConsole) {
      return {
        ...oldConsole,
        log: function(msg) {
          window.webkit.messageHandlers.iosListener.postMessage(msg);
          oldConsole[level](msg);
        }
      }
    })(window.console);
```

Then you will receive `msg` of all your `console.log(msg)` in the message handler you have specified.

If you want to track more than just the console.log you can elaborate the script with something like this:

```swift
extension WKWebView {

     func redirectConsole(messageHandlerName: String) {
        let script = """
        var console = (function (oldConsole) {
          function redirect(level) {
            return function(msg) {
              window.webkit.messageHandlers.\(messageHandlerName).postMessage({ method: "console", level: level, content: JSON.stringify(msg) })
              oldConsole[level](msg);
            };
          }
          return {
            ...oldConsole,
            log: redirect("log"),
            info: redirect("info"),
            warn: redirect("warn"),
            error: redirect("error"),
          }
        })(window.console);
        """
        evaluateJavaScript(script) { _, error in
            if let error = error {
                log(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...and I process the log from the webview in my messageHandler.

Comment: Do you have sample of this implementation